# What can we say about AM[log n]?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, interactive-proofs

It is known that $\textbf{AM}[O(1)] = \textbf{AM}$.

Since $\textbf{IP}=\textbf{PSPACE}$ we have $\textbf{AM}[poly(n)] = \textbf{PSPACE}$.

Can we say something about $\textbf{AM}[ f(n)]$, where $f$ is a function between  $O(1)$ and $poly(n)$?

(For example, $f(n) = \log n$.)

Comment: https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#ampolylog ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Careful, you are next to a caged animal.